# Domains not showing default values when under edit in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, domains

I am having trouble displaying the field value when it is under edit.
I have published a Web App on my server that displays a number of fields through pop-ups on the feature layer. I've used domains with these fields to lock-in what the user can enter.

The default value does not show up where I have enabled domains. This is a bit of a problem, as the user would like to see what is already entered before they make their selection.

Is there a way to make the default value visible on-top of the domain selection, instead of it saying *Keep Existing Value*?

I've set up my domains using properties, feature class, and the Domain option within subtypes.

[image: Default Value that I want to show]

[image: "Keep existing value" - would like this replaced with actual value]

[image: List of options from Domain]

[image]

Comment: No sure if this helps but the inability to view the original data extends to the web maps that I've published as a feature layer. The fields with domain assigned appear as blank when under edit.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the edit. It'd be good if someone could help answer the question. Regards.